# How to stop Time data being appended to Today() (powerapps and excel)

Tags: datetime, powerapps

I am trying to use powerapps to create a submission form for users.

The issue is that I have one field for submission date.
All I want is the short date added to the table column when the user clicks submit.

What I get is the shortdate with

YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSOZ

[image: Problem]

I have tried:

`Text(Today(), "[%-en-US]YYYY-MM-DD")`

`Text(Today(), DateTimeFormat.ShortDate)`

`Left(Text(Today(), "[%-en-US]YYYY-MM-DD"),10)`

`Left(Text(Today(), DateTimeFormat.ShortDate),10)`

I have tried setting the excel table field to "Text"

I have tried setting it back to date and using just the short date without conversion.
Is there any end to this madness?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(Today(),DateTimeFormat.ShortDate)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick;

```
DateValue(Text(Now()))
```